# How do I pass the results of a user submitted html form to django urls?

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I have a Django Url pattern for my search filter as follows:

> url(r'^search/(?P.+)$', views.search, name='search'),

That way, if I call, say /search/1+Timothy, the url goes to my search view, which returns the results of my query - in this case, all entries in 1 Timothy.  So far, so good.

In my page, I wanted to add a simple call to this search function.  So, I thought, why not a simple form?

```
    <FORM method='GET' action='/search/'>
        <!-- Note: Calls /search?filter_range=entered_reference is handled in urls.py-->
        <LABEL for="filter_range">Show References</LABEL>
        <INPUT id='filter_range' name='filter_range' type='text' placeholder='search' value='' />
        <INPUT type='submit' />
    </FORM>
```

Which should be equal to a simple:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?filter_range=1+timothy
```

Problem is, I can't figure out how to specify that in the urls.py:

```
url(r'^search/\\?passage=(?P<filter_range>.+)$', views.search, name='search'),
url(r'^search/(?P<filter_range>.+)$', views.search, name='search'),
```

doesn't work, nor can I seem to figure out a regular expression that does.  So, how do I get the output of the form in my template to callback to a url that urls.py can find?

Comment: And yes, before anyone asks, I've tried search?filter_range too.. :)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can't use named parameters/url segments using GET as the form method. Those values would be appended to the querystring as values: ?foo=bar. You would just point to your base view URL pattern, and the pick up the values from request.GET.get('your-param')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not worrry about the GET parameters in the URL.

Try this:

```
url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
```

and in views

```
def search():
    filter_range = request.GET.get('filter_range', '')
    #rest of the code.
```

You have the flexibility of sending across any number of GET parameters without having to declare them in the urls.py

Some more context in [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) here

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve query parameters via urlconfs. They can be accessed via the request object which is always available in django views. Example:

```
request.GET.get('searchvalue')
```

For more details please take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/.

Comment: No. It would have been +1 for using `request.GET`, but it is completely wrong to say search forms should be POSTs. POST is for actions that modify data: searches do not do this. You might even want to bookmark a search result, which you can only do with a GET.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, you're right. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a small followup, this is exactly how I was able to re-use my function in place:

From views.py

```
def search(request, filter_range):
    search_ref = BibleReference(filter_range)
    qry_in_range = "SELECT * FROM concordance_reference WHERE ref_book_num=%s AND ref_endchapter_num >= %s AND ref_endverse_num >= %s AND ref_startchapter_num <= %s AND ref_startverse_num <= %s ORDER BY ref_book_num, ref_startchapter_num, ref_startverse_num, ref_endchapter_num, ref_endverse_num"
    params = tuple([search_ref.book_num, search_ref.start_chapter, search_ref.start_verse, search_ref.end_chapter, search_ref.end_verse]) 

    found_references_list = VerseReference.objects.raw(qry_in_range, params)

    template = loader.get_template('concordance/index.html')
    context = RequestContext( request, {
        'filter_range': filter_range,
        'filter_ref': search_ref,
        'found_references_list': found_references_list,
        })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

def empty_search(request):
    filter_range = request.GET.get('filter_range', '')
    return search(request, filter_range)
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^search/$', views.empty_search, name='empty_search'),
url(r'^search/(?P<filter_range>.+)$', views.search, name='search'),
```

The advantage of this approach is that my restful urls:
/search/1+Timothy  remain good, and
/search/?filter_range=1+Timothy  can still be called from my form.